# NotePad++ - Replace 100+ unique lines in file with new unique lines

Tags: search, text, replace, find, notepad++

I am trying to take a large text file and replace about 140 rows of the data with brand new rows of data. I have all the rows I need to replace in a text file, along with the new rows, but can't figure out a way to batch/loop through each record, find the specific row based on what's in the file, and then replace that line/value based on what's in the file. I'm trying to avoid doing 140 manually search and replace functions, any help would be appreciated.

I've tried a few different Python scripts from here, but none of them seem to work with my specific fact pattern.

Comment: Could you show us your Python script attemps? And give sample files and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you has 140 search and replace items, and wanna quickly complete these replacement.

Perhaps EmEditor's "**Batch Replace**" feature may be helpful.

First, create a Link file in TXT format, and write all search and replace strings into it: the first column is the search string, and the second is the replacement string.

See Help here:https://www.emeditor.org/en/dlg_replace_index.html

Press Ctrl+H to open replace dialog. Click button "batch>>" to switch into **Batch Replace**. Drag and drop this linked file onto the "**Batch Replace**" dialog box, and then click the "Batch Replace" button to complete all replacements.
[image]